# Extract pattern from a string in r

Tags: r, regex, string

I have the following array of `chr`

```
v<-c("RT @name1: hello world", "@nickname1: bye bye guys", "RT @name2_surname2: I have no text", "Hello!")
```

I would like to select only the element that start with `RT` and select, in another array, `w` e.g., only the names between `@` and `:`. For example:

```
> w
 "name1"    "name2_surname2"
```

Maybe I could use function `str_extract_all` by package `stringr` but I can't apply it to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `base R`, you can use `gsub()` along with `grepl()`

```
# pattern for matching
pat <- "^RT.*?@(.*?):.*"
# for string this starts with RT, extract the segment between @ and :
res <- gsub(pat,"\\1",v[grepl(pat,v)])
```

such that

```
> res
[1] "name1"          "name2_surname2"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `str_extract` we can use lookahead lookbehind regex.

```
w <- stringr::str_extract(v, "(?<=^RT @).*(?=:)")
w[!is.na(w)]
#[1] "name1"          "name2_surname2"
```

---

We can do this with `str_match` as well

```
stringr::str_match(v, "^RT @(.*):")[, 2]
#[1] "name1"          NA               "name2_surname2" NA
```

and remove the `NA` values.

---

Using base R, that can be achieved with `regmatches` and `gregexpr`

```
unlist(regmatches(v, gregexpr("(?<=^RT @).*(?=:)", v, perl = TRUE)))
#[1] "name1"          "name2_surname2"
```